# receiving onPaste / onChange through a component that returns input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Essentially I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<MyTextInput onChange={console.log("Change")} />
```

this component simply returns an `<input type="text" />`
and nothing happens when I type inside it (reason for using component here is to add further layout around input in the future). Also `event.target.value` is undefined on MyTextInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need pass event handler down to the child component,
and then call `onChange` callback inside `MyTextInput` component,

```
var MyTextInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input onChange={ this.props.onChange } />;
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <MyTextInput onChange={ (e) => { console.log(e.target.value) } } />
    </div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/30852/)